# Undo specific local commit before push

Tags: git

I accidentally committed a `zip` of the whole solution 4 commits ago. I realized this after I tried to push and git bash showed I was uploading something larger than 100mb.

So far I've tried to:

- Delete the file locally and commit that change (this still leaves the huge `packfile` which still seems to be causing a problem when pushing)
- Used `git revert -n c5d1516c` (which is the specific commit that includes the zip. I figured I would then add `.zip` to the `gitignore` then commit that and hope the 600mb `pack` file would resolve itself but this is not working either)

I've tried a few other approaches but I'm not the best at git so I'm at a loss of direction

Here is my commit history. The highlighted one is the one that contains the zip file that I need to remove and also remove from git history.
[image]

**How can I undo the highlighted commit so that I can ignore the zip file and fix my pack file issue?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following can be done safely only if you haven't pushed yet.

You could do `rebase -i` and remove the commit. Personally I don't like rebasing because there are a lot of actions happening under the hood. And you may want to remove only 1 file from the bad commit.

So if you're okay with **squashing** your local changes into 1 commit, then it's easier:

1. `git reset --soft [commit hash before zip]`
2. remove zip file
3. Commit all your local changes

Comment: Such a simple solution. I spent 2 hours now trying so many different things. *womp*

Answer (score 0):

You have accepted an answer already but it looks like you have basically "lost" the 4 revisions that you had made and you got a single revision saying "This is the work of 4 other revisions that I busted for not being careful". A much better solution that would keep your whole history as it was while removing the zip would be (assumming we are working on master):

```
git checkout master~4 # go back to where the zip was added
git rm --cached the-zip-file.zip # remove the zip file from revision
git commit --amend --no-edit # commit without zip file, leaving everything else as is
git cherry-pick master~4..master # replicate revisions created on top of busted revision
git branch -f master # move master to new revision
git checkout master
```

At this point you kept your history while removing the zip file.

Comment: Which is basically the manual way of doing `git rebase -i` like th accepted answer already mentions, isn't it?

Comment: Oh! Totally missed it. Just looked at the recipe and didn't read what had been written before. Not that **git rebase -i** is _totally_ automatic, but anyway. It's fine.